# Track Gets Looped And Never Stop Even With "isPlaying"

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a list of songs, the "PlaySong" method is as the following :

```
if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        Log.i("MUSICSTATE","isPlaying");
    }else if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);//or InputStream etc.
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        Log.i("MUSICSTATE", "ELSE");
    }
```

When i press the button to play, the "else" condition always happen, and if i press the button again, the "else" will happen again, no matter what, it gets looped .

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`nMediaPLayer.isPlaying()` only shows the value of a variable. You need to set the value to !0 in the `else{}` block, which `start()` is obviously not doing. Log the value of `isPlaying()` at the end of the `else{}` block to see for yourself. Have a closer look at the declarations, there must be a func like `nMediaPlayer.setPlaying(TRUE)`.

Comment: isPlaying MUST return the playing state, If no, Then why did they add it ? "setPlaying" or any related method isn't there, I might be some custom way to check for isplaying .